# Trigger function only if another function has finished in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

How is it possible to trigger a function only if another function has finished?

In my actual usecase I need to trigger this three functions one after another:

```
dLoad();
masonry();
stylefix();
```

Comment: Your code already accomplishes that, if the functions are synchronous

Comment: @RE666 can you add more detail about what those 3 functions do ? Are they synchronous ? Asynchronous ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your functions are synchronous, it is already accomplished the way you wrote it. If they're not (or some of them are not)- you can group them under one async function and await the asynchronous ones, like so:

```
async function func(){
  await dLoad(); // async function
  masonry(); // synchronous function
  await stylefix(); // async function
}
```

another possible case is that your functions are synchronous, but has some async operations inside, for example- lets say `masonry()` does that. what would happen in this case would be:

dLoad > masonry(without async operation) > stylefix > msonry's async operation.

It might be ok with you, as this is the definition for "the function is done" as you wrote it- it could be you do not need this async operation to complete in order to define `masonry` as "done" and move on to execute `stylefix`.

However, if you do need all async operations inside `masonry` to complete, you also need to make it into async function and `await` the async op inside that function. You won't have to `await` for it outside if you do not return the promise explicitely, but it will be more readable and obvious this is an async function this way.

Comment: async functions always return a promise

Comment: well I did assume this basic JS knowledge in my answer.. ill clarify it a bit